# Simple way to display "years of service" in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to display a number for years of service on a website. Essentially I thought I could put in a start date and current date to have an output of the years in between.

I can gt the current year using the following code but am unsure how to calculate the deference

```js
document.write(2010) + (/\d{4}/.exec(Date())[0])
```

Comment: Check out `Date#getUtcFullYear` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear . Also your syntax is pretty confusing. All that code is going to do is write `2010` to the document. You need to do calculations and THEN document.write

Comment: Thank you for the info, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subtract `2010` from the current year and concatenate the string:

```js
document.write((/\d{4}/.exec(Date())[0]) - 2010 + ' years of service')
```

Although an easier way to get the year is to use `Date.getFullYear()`:

```js
document.write(new Date().getFullYear() - 2010 + ' years of service')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date` functions to extract components of time.
To get year you can use something like:

```
today = new Date();
year = today.getFullYear();
```

To calculate difference between years (`year` value is number):

```
d = year - 2010;
```

Comment: Thank you, everyone answers have helped so much. Seems I was over thinking/complicating the code

Answer (score 0):

You can get like this

```js
document.write(new Date().getFullYear() - 2010)
```

document.write(new Date().getFullYear() - 2010)